# run a centos8 container on a centos7 host iptables duplicate

Tags: docker, iptables, centos8

when run a centos8 container on a centos7 host. in the container, add a iptables rule to one CHAIN(eg, filter table INPUT CHAIN), the rule will not only be added to INPUT CHAIN ,but also other CHAINs(eg OUTPUT,FORWARD, even  PREROUTING,POSTROUTING)

1. run a centos8 container on a centos7 host

`docker run -it --privileged centos:8 sh`

2. when it running, install iptables in container

```
yum install -y iptables
```

3. show iptables version: `iptables -V`

```
iptables version: v1.8.4 (nf_tables)
```

4. list current rules: `iptables -t nat -nvL`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
```

5. add a new rule: `iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -j REJECT`
6. list rules again: `iptables -nvL`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
```

and I have test if run centos8 container on a centos8 host,this would not happen.

Answer (score 0):

In one word: host and container mix iptables and nftables.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71305

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1668007